# QuillJS Reload toolbar controls

Tags: quill

I am using QuillJS and I need to add some controls to toolbar during runtime. Is there any way to make it from code after whole Quill has been initialized?

This is how I make it now.

```
quillEditor.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('color', (value) => {
    if (value == 'new-color') {
        value = prompt('Give me hex color baby!');

        // unfortunately this code does not work    
        let n = toolbar.querySelector('select.ql-color');
        n.innerHTML += '<option value="'+value+'"></option>';
    }

    quillEditor.format('color', value);
    console.log("Color handler", value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're only adding the new options to the select element which is hidden. The element used in the UI to select colors is a span with the class `ql-picker-options`.

Check out this snippet

```js
var tools = [
 ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
  [{'color': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'new-color']}]
]

var quillEditor = new Quill('#editor-container', {
 modules: {
   toolbar: tools
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});

var toolbar = document.querySelector('.ql-toolbar');

quillEditor.getModule('toolbar').addHandler('color', (value) => {
    if (value == 'new-color') {
        value = prompt('Give me hex color baby!');
        
        // This element is what the user sees
        let uiSelect = toolbar.querySelector('.ql-color .ql-picker-options');
        
        // This is a hidden element
        let select = toolbar.querySelector('select.ql-color');
        
        uiSelect.innerHTML += '<span class="ql-picker-item ql-primary" data-value="'+value+'" style="background-color: '+value+';"></span>';
        select.innerHTML += '<option value="'+value+'"></option>';
    }

    quillEditor.format('color', value);
});
```

```css
.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=new-color] {
  background: none !important;
  width: 90px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
}
.ql-color .ql-picker-options [data-value=new-color]:before {
  content: 'New Color';
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="editor-container"></div>
```

Then with [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), you could keep the "New Color" option at the end.